# Replacing these methods with faster ones

Tags: c++, boost

This question is actually an update to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963563/smart-pointer-wrapping-penalty-memoization-with-stdmap/15964007?noredirect=1#comment22757010_15964007) that I had posted. From user opinions I realized that I needed to profile my code so I profiled the first part of my code through Vtune Amp. and I got the following statements that consume significant time as compared to other methods

```
Source Line Source                                                                        CPU Time by Utilization   Overhead Time   Spin Time
double high_val =  atof(temp[2].c_str());                                                                           
std::string s( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&buffer)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());            
boost::split( temp, lines[i], boost::is_any_of(",") );
```

In the above code buffer is:
`boost::asio::streambuf buffer`;

any suggestions on replacement functions for the above ?

Comment: What is `buffer` type?

Comment: Ok, I see. What do you intend to do with `s`? To really need to create this object or maybe you can work on `buffer.data()` directly?

Comment: The only reason I am copying the buffer to a string is because I want to pass this string to next statement `boost::split()`

Comment: So it's actually `temp`, not `s`?

Comment: once the string is made it is sent to various different methods. The methods further split this string using boost::split and the vector the string is split into is `lines`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Boost.Sprit` for all your parsing tasks. If you've got a lot of rules, it might consume more compile-time resources, but it will be fast at run-time.

For the first line:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
std::string::iterator begin = temp.begin() + 2;
std::string::iterator end = input.end();
float high_val;
boost::spirit::qi::parse(begin, end, boost::spirit::float_, high_val);
```

For the last line:

```
std::vector<std::string>;
// '%' is a list parser
boost::spirit::qi::parse(buffer.data(), buffer.data() + buffer.size(), *(char_ - ',') % ',', lines);
```

Most likely, it's possible to create one simple grammar for all your task, but I don't know what you're parsing exactly, so I just tried to match your above code more or less.

Comment: How would I do something like this in boost spirit `boost::algorithm::split_regex( Vector, string, boost::regex( "\r\n" ) ) ;`

Comment: Is the stack vector called `lines` ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar as I've shown above, you can split anything with % parser. Of course, you have to learn Spirit (at least its `Qi` part - for parsing) to work with it effectively (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html).

Comment: @Rajeshwar What is your input format *exactly*, and what do you need to get out of it?

Comment: Thanks for you reply and guidance. I am currently going through the spirit docs. Ill post questions here if I have any. It seems like spirit could also solve a lot of my issues. Thanks again

Comment: @Rajeshwar You're welcome. Spirit has a slight learning curve, but once you get used to it you see how elegant, convenient and powerful it is.