# Wrapping C++ functionalities from std, is sometimes a bad idea?

Tags: c++

My question is about wrapping some containers or objects from the std library, and the cost of doing so.
Let's say I need to create a `ThreadSafeStack` class. I would wrap the `std::stack` container and use mutexes to make it thread safe. This would be totally ok because the functionalities of the new `ThreadSafeStack` would be worth the cost (function calls). But what if I want to wrap the `std::mutex` into a class `MyMutex` to add logging functionalities when debugging ? In your opinion, would it be worth it or not ?

And what if I do something like that only for convenience, to avoid writing `std::` or `using::std` in all my files ? Do you think it is stupid ?

I have read a bit about function calls (like [this](http://hbfs.wordpress.com/2008/12/30/the-true-cost-of-calls/) for example) and I would say that it would not be a big overhead.

Comment: Your wrapper function calls most likely will be inlined on proper optimization level, resulting in *ZERO* overhead. For example check [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15964113/1762344): pointer dereference wrapped into `operator*` results in identical assembler code to raw pointer dereference. Many levels of C++ abstractions can be evaporate during optimization.

Comment: I would also add that if you're doing IO (e.g. writing to a log file) then a function call is the least of your concerns.

Comment: You're right @selalerer.

Comment: Thanks for the example @Evgeny Panasyuk. Could we consider your quick answer as being an answer ?

Comment: this is the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which I find very useful when done correctly. Read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This would be totally ok because the functionalities of the new ThreadSafeStack would be worth the cost (function calls).

Your wrapper function calls most likely will be inlined on proper optimization level, resulting in ZERO overhead. For example check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963563/smart-pointer-wrapping-penalty-memoization-with-stdmap/15964113#15964113): pointer dereference wrapped into `operator*` results in identical assembler code to raw pointer dereference. Many levels of C++ abstractions can be evaporated during optimization.

Though, virtual function calls are very unlikely to be inlined. So use normal functions whenever it makes sense.

> But what if I want to wrap the std::mutex into a class MyMutex to add logging functionalities when debugging ?

Logging may add some significant cost, but if you need it only during debugging - you can safely disable it on release builds via `ifdef`s or by any other means, like:

```
const bool do_logging = false; // somewhere
// ...
if(do_logging) // branching can be easily removed by optimizer,
               // because do_logging is constant
    // ...
else
    // ...
```

> In your opinion, would it be worth it or not ?

Yes, of course. It is common practice to build more useful abstractions based on standard library facilities.

> And what if I do something like that only for convenience, to avoid writing std:: or using::std in all my files ? Do you think it is stupid ?

It depends on your project - in some cases it is even OK to use `using namespace std` in header files. But note - someone who will include such header may face name clashes.

In most cases it is OK to use `using namespace std` at the head of `.cpp` files (after `inlucde`s). But even if that is not acceptable you can always use `using` directive at function level:

```
void foo()
{
     using namespace std;
     // ...
}
```